# How to open serial port from a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

For a few weeks I'm stuck with, how to open a serial COM port from a thread, 
to be able to write/read it from another thread. In my example, when I write to the port from another thread, there is access denied.
When I open the port from Main GUI, it works fine, I can write it from the thread, but I need to give a user possibility to choose the COM number.
This is my code, if anybody could take a look and help, it would be great...

```
class Connect(QThread): 
    connectResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)  
    position1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    actuPosResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, myvar, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.myvar = str(myvar) # value from spinbox
    def run(self):
        self.pserial = serial.Serial()
        try:
            COMnumber= self.myvar
            self.pserial = serial.Serial('COM'+COMnumber, 115200,timeout=None)
            r='COM '+COMnumber+' connected.'
            self.pserial.write("c".encode('ascii')+"\n".encode('ascii'))  
            incomingByte = self.pserial.read()
            decodedByte = incomingByte.decode("utf-8")
            if decodedByte == ('c'):
                r='Atmega On-Line'
                self.connectResult.emit(r)
                pos1='---'
                self.position1.emit(pos1)
            else :
                r='   No answer from Atmega.'
                self.connectResult.emit(r)
    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()
class ReadingEncoder(QThread):  
    actuPosResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str) 
    def __init__(self, mojazmienna, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.mojazmienna = str(mojazmienna)
    def run(self):
    Try:
          self.pserial = serial.Serial()
          self.pserial = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200,timeout=1)
           self.pserial.write("p".encode('ascii')+"\n".encode('ascii')) 
            incomingByte = self.pserial.read()
            decodedByte = incomingByte.decode("utf-8")
            actualPos = ''
         if decodedByte == ('a'):        
                while decodedByte != ('\n'):
                    incomingByte = self.pserial.read()
                  decodedByte = incomingByte.decode("utf-8")
                  actualPos = actualPos + decodedByte
                 pos= actualPos.rstrip('\n')# pozycja w formacie string
                 print(pos)
             self.actuPosResult.emit(pos)
        except (EOFError, OSError, IOError, ValueError, RuntimeError, BrokenPipeError, InterruptedError, TimeoutError): 
            print('Thread  readingEncoder error')
        self.pserial.close()
```

Comment: TL;TR could you please simplify and post a shorter example. What is the problem? Any stack trace?

Comment: The problem is, when I open the serial port from Connect thread, I can't acces it from ReadingEncoder thread.

Answer (score 1):

You just open the serial port and start the thread.

```
import atexit

class SerialPort(QThread):
    connectResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)  
    position1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    actuPosResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, port=None, baud=115200, timeout=1):
        super().__init__()

        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        self.ser.port = port
        self.ser.baudrate = baud
        self.ser.timeout = timeout
        self.running = False
        atexit.register(self.ser.close) # Make sure the serial port closes when you quit the program.

    def set_port(port_num):
        self.ser.port = "COM"+str(port_num)

    def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.running = True
        self.ser.open()
        super().start()
        self.ser.write("c\n".encode("ascii"))

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                incomingByte = self.ser.read()
                decodedByte = incomingByte.decode("utf-8")
                if decodedByte == ('c'):
                    r='Atmega On-Line'
                    self.connectResult.emit(r)
                    pos1='---'
                    self.position1.emit(pos1)
                else:
                    r='   No answer from Atmega.'
                    self.connectResult.emit(r)
            except:
                pass
            # time.sleep(0.01) # You may want to sleep or use readline
```

You use this class by having a button call the start method.

```
serial = SerialPort("COM3")
btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Connect")
btn.clicked.connect(serial.start)
```

You can typically only open a serial port once unless you know that you have both ends available to you.

The serial port exists on the main thread and exists the entire time. You don't need to continuously open and close the serial port. All of the reading happens in the thread. To write just call `serial.write(b"c\n")`. You shouldn't need the writing to happen in the thread.

To have the user select the com port just use a QLineEdit.

```
myserial = QtGui.QLineEdit("3")
myserial.textChanged.connect(serial.set_port)
```

Comment: It looks that it works. Thanks a lot. I made small modifications to my necessity's but communication and encoding works fine. Before closing the subject, I have another question: After closing the app. I have the message: "StdErr: QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running". How to stop the thread, before closing the application? Please let me know If I have to make a new  topic with this question...

Comment: That means that your QThread is still running when the application exits. In the code above I use atexit to close the serial port. The atexit should register a function that stops the thread and closes the serial port. You can stop the thread by setting `self.running = False` and then waiting for the QThread to exit the run method and close. You may also have to call stop or terminate on the QThread.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open the port multiple times.

Instead of doing that, you have a couple of alternatives;

- Create a `Serial` object once, and pass it to the thread that has to work with it.
- Provide the name of the serial port to use to the the thread that has to work with it, and let it open the port.

In both cases make sure that your thread closes the port properly when it exits!